# Como deserializar Array JSON em um Array de Objetos?

Tags: c#, json, .net, node.js

Estou há um tempo tentando Deserializar um retorno JSON da minha api em nodeJS.
Já tentei de muitas maneiras e nada de sucesso.

**Tenho o seguinte JSON de retorno da request do client.**

```
  "response": {
    "count": 1,
    "produtos": [
      {
        "id_produto": 1,
        "produto": "teste",
        "preco": 1455.99,
        "request": {
          "tipo": "GET",
          "descricao": "Retorna os detalhes de um produto específico.",
          "url": "http://localhost:3000/produtos/1"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**Já no lado do cliente tenho seguintes códigos:**

Tenho uma classe para cada objeto equivalente no json.

```
        //Representa o objeto 'response' em json
        public class ResponseObject
        {
            public List<ProdutoResponse> response { get; set; }

        }

        //Representa o array 'produtos' em json
        public class ProdutoResponse
        {
            public List<ListProdutos> produtos { get; set; }
        }

        //Especifica os campos do objetos dentro do array 'produtos' em json
        public class ListProdutos
        {
            public int id_produto { get; set; }
            public string produto { get; set; }
            public float preco { get; set; }
            public List<ListResquetStatus> request { get; set; }


        }
        //Especifica os campos dentro do objeto 'request'
        public class ListResquetStatus
        {
            public string tipo { get; set; }
            public string descricao { get; set; }
            public string url { get; set; }

        }
```

**Aqui Deserializo o json: Porém me retorna um valor nulo**

```
  static void JsonShowDes()
        {
            JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();

            var productsInfos = ser.Deserialize<List<ResponseObject>>(Get_json().ToString());           

        }
```

[image: log]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usei a estrutura assim:

```
public class Request
{
    public string tipo { get; set; }
    public string descricao { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
}

public class Produto
{
    public int id_produto { get; set; }
    public string produto { get; set; }
    public double preco { get; set; }
    public Request request { get; set; }
}

public class Response
{
    public int count { get; set; }
    public List<Produto> produtos { get; set; }
}

public class ResponseObject
{
    public Response response { get; set; }
}
```

Para testar usei o `Newtonsoft`, pois teste usando uma class e esse package é simples de instalar, e deserializa com sucesso:

```
var productsInfos = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResponseObject>(json);
```

Tem duas diferenças, do seu modelo, 1 que, pelo json, faz não serializar:
Na sua class `ResponseObject` tem um `List<ProdutoResponse>`, sendo que json, "respose" é um objeto, não um array (se vier mais um, deveria ser um `Dictiornary`). Além disso, faltou a propriedade `Count` em `ProdutoResponse`.

Pode ver funcionando aqui: https://dotnetfiddle.net/FcBpZ0

Comment: Mano vc é de mais, nossa funcionou perfeitamente. Muito obrigado ;) abração

Answer (score 0):

Altere seu `ResponseObject` para:

```
public class ResponseObject
{
    //public int count { get; set; }
    
    public ProdutoResponse response { get; set; }
}
```

Se atente também que você está usando `id_produtos` (com **s** no final) na sua classe `ListProdutos`, sendo que no json tá somente `id_produto`.

Comment: Confundi aqui, vou alterar a resposta.

Comment: Obrigado pela correção. Fiz a devida alteração no código, porém nada mudou, recebo nulo ainda

Comment: Alterei de novo.